# How to call a web service from Ant script or from within Jenkins?

Tags: web-services, ant

I am using Ant Script in Jenkins to handle the deployment of my files.  What I want to do is to trigger a call to a URL that has the web service.  My question is, how can I do that from Ant Script or from within Jenkins?

Thanks in advance,
Monte

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Option 1: "get" task

Ant's [get task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html) can be used to invoke web services, but it restricted to GET operations. Only works for very simple web services

### Option 2: curl

Invoke the unix *curl* command to call the webservice (See this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/149329/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-with-the-curl-command-line-tool) for examples)

```
<target name="invoke-webservice">
    <exec executable="curl">
        <arg line="-d 'param1=value1&param2=value2' http://example.com/resource.cgi"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

**Note:**

The *curl* command could also be invoked as a post build action in Jenkins

### Option 3: Groovy ANT task

If you need a cross platform and flexible solution embed groovy script within your build to invoke the web service.

```
<target name="invoke-webservice">
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

    <groovy>
        import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON
        import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient

        def client = new RESTClient("http://localhost:5498/")
        def response = client.put(path: "parking_tickets",
                                  requestContentType: JSON, 
                                  contentType: JSON)

        log.info "response status: ${response.status}"
    </groovy>
</target>
```

### Option 4: Groovy Jenkins post build

Use the [Groovy Postbuild plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) to invoke the web service.

### Option 5: ANT HTTP task

The [ANT HTTP task](http://code.google.com/p/missing-link/) is an alternative to the groovy task above

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Implement a WebService Client with Java (by example Netbeans can generate it in seconds).
2. Upload the jar of the client to subversion where can be accesible from Jenkins.
3. Execute the client from ANT.

```
     <target name="run">
          <java jar="ws_client/WSClient.jar"/>
     </target>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  In my case though, the web service would be written in ColdFusion instead of Java.

Comment: The language agnostic nature of Webservices, let you write the client of the web service in any language. My recomendation is to pick the language that will be most comfortable for you.

Answer (score 0):

Related to question - how to call WebServices from Ant.
In my case, **Anteater** helped to properly call and receive response from semi-complicated case.
http://aft.sourceforge.net/index.html

```
<soapRequest>
```

Is the task you might want to take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **Groovy-wslite**. The project page can be found [here](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite). Works like a charm, easy to integrate and intuitive to use. I've had a similar problem today and put some example code in my question / answer: [Axis2 with complexTypes in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795847/axis2-with-complextypes-in-groovy)