# Axis2 with complexTypes in Groovy

Tags: web-services, ant, groovy, apache-axis, groovyws

So I'm having a couple of ANT scripts using Groovy to process complex calculations normal ANT can't do (at least afaik). I'm trying to access an Axis2 web service using a SOAP-envelope via Groovy. The request and response is pretty simple, except for two `complexType` attributes (one in the request, one in the response).

The first thing I've stumbled across was **Groovy Soap**. It is quite easy to use, you simply instantiate a SoapClient and call the web service method. Unfortunately it cannot handle `complexType` attributes in the request, which I need:

> Current Limitations:
>
> ....
>
> 4: Custom data types cannot be processed on client side when using the Groovy SOAP module with the current groovy-1.0 release.

Then I've read a lot about **GroovyWS**. I created my Grape config file in my `user.home`, javac and $GROOVY_HOME are available (basically did everything as described on the [project quick guide page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyWS)). Grape somehow retrieved Ivy, when I first started the script (I have no experience with Grape, but I suspect it's very similar to Maven).

Then started my simple script:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules', module='groovyws',version='0.5.2')
import groovyx.net.ws.WSClient
proxy = new WSClient("http://127.0.0.1/axis2/services/ReleaseService?wsdl", this.class.classLoader)
proxy.initialize()
```

Unfortunately I couldn't even initialize the web client (without the Groovy Soap library in the classpath):

```
SEVERE: Could not compile java files for http://127.0.0.1/axis2/services/ReleaseService?wsdl.
Caught: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create JAXBContext for generated packages: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "com.intershop.qa.tae.ws.xsd" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create JAXBContext for generated packages: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated [...]
```

With the Groovy Soap library (which seems to overload some of GroovyWS' functionality) in the classpath I've got:

```
Caught: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.wsdl.xml.WSDLReader.readWSDL(Ljavax/wsdl/xml/WSDLLocator;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;)Ljavax/wsdl/Definition; java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
```

which looks very similar to the error I've got when I was using Groovy Soap in the first place.

***So my question is:*** How can I communicate with an Axis2 web service using `complexType` parameters via ANT. I'm not limited to Groovy only, but for deployment reasons (~50 VM snapshots) I want something simple. A Java client worked, but since the deployment is quite some effort (especially if I want to change stuff in the future) I need something which is closer to ANT and easier to deploy.

Thanks in advance for suggestions of other technologies or fix ideas for my GroovyWS implementation.

Comment: Please report when you finally make it. I can't help you except pointing to another so question: [How to call a web service from Ant script or from within Jenkins?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303365/how-to-call-a-web-service-from-ant-script-or-from-within-jenkins). If you come up with something better, you could also answer that question.

Comment: So what was the problem? Why GroovyWS did not work from the start?

Comment: Tbh I don't really know. It wasn't even able to initialize properly. Maybe some problems with Grape. And as mentioned I believe that it used Groovy Soap the time I had the library still included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with a solution: **[groovy-wslight](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite)** actually solved my problem and was finally able to deploy easily and access the web service without problems/exceptions.

The script:

```
@Grab(group='com.github.groovy-wslite', module='groovy-wslite', version='0.7.1')
import wslite.soap.*
def client = new SOAPClient("http://127.0.0.1/axis2/services/ReleaseService")
def response = client.send  {
  body {
    myFunction(xmlns:"http://my.namespace.com") {
       stringParameter("6.3.0.0")
       status() { value("default") }
       mode() { value("full") }
    }
  }
}
```

Where `status` and `mode` are `complexTypes` which consist of one "value" attribute (as an example).

```
println(response.myFunctionResponse.return)
```

gives me the object returned by the web service. Of course the names of the tokens depend on the WSDL. In my case the response of the request is called `myFunctionResponse`, which has a field `name="return"` and gives me a `complexType` object. The fields of the object can be retrieved according to the names given in the WSDL:

```
println(response.myFunctionResponse.return.location) // gives me the field value of the field "location" for my complexType
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using JDK 1.7. Switching to JDK 1.6 solved it for me.