# In TeamCity, using the Rest API, can I find all Related project configurations?

Tags: python, rest, ant, teamcity

Using an Ant or Python script, and the TeamCity Rest API, how can I identify all related projects and configurations, and check their status.  In other words, I have a project with an installer configuration, that before I execute this installer configuration, I want to ensure that any configurations in any related other projects are successfully completed.  I just want information (some kind of hierarchal list), I do not want to run the installer and have the snapshot\artifact dependencies start the configurations in the other projects.

I am thinking along the lines of a loop, that for this installer configuration, checks that the dependencies have successfully completed, and then goes and checks those other projects to see if their dependencies have successfully completed, etc., etc.  This script would be run outside of Teamcity by anyone having the proper access, and just pass something like the BuildType id of the installer configuration.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303365/how-to-call-a-web-service-from-ant-script-or-from-within-jenkins/8317597#8317597

Comment: I know how to use Python and the Rest API, I am just not sure how to use it to get what I am looking for (or if the information that I am looking for can be retrieved).

Comment: Then you have tagged the question incorrectly. This is a question about the team city product. I have added the "teamcity" tag.